# I have below dataset and i want to change this data into target output datatset on the basis of number of repetitions

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below dataset and i want to make repititions of my rows that number of times and assign index to them.

Thanks in advance. Every suggestion is appreciated :)

INPUT:

```
Col1    col2    col3    repetition
101 test1   10      2
102 test2   20      1
103 test3   30      2
104 test4   40      1
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1            col2           col3       index
101     test1       10      1
101     test1       10      2
102     test2       20      1
103     test3       30      1
103     test3       30      2
104     test4       40      1
```

Comment: is this a School Assignment?

Answer (score -1):

Here is some java code that describes the algorithm to accomplish this:

```html
List<InputType> inputList = getInput();
List<OutputType> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

foreach(InputType input in inputList){
 for(int index = 1; index <= input.repetition){
  OutputType output = new OutputType(input.col1, input.col2, input.col3, index);
  outputList.add(output)
 }
}

System.out.println(outputList);
```